# Angular - Passing object to @Input parameter with routerlink

Tags: angular, routerlink

I have an angular component with a @Input parameter as follows.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-transmission-history'
})
export class TransmissionHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() theRecord: Record = null;

  constructor(private _transmissionHistoryService: TransmissionHistoryService) { }
}
```

In another component I have this in the markup:

```
<app-transmission-history [theRecord]="selectedRecord"></app-transmission-history>
```

Perfect.  Everything works as expected.

I need to move the app-transmission-history component to a stand alone page.  Now I need to access it with routerLink as follows:

```
<a routerLink='/transmissionHistory'>{{selectedRecord.Name}}</a>
```

I can't figure out how to set the @Input parameter in the routerlink in the markup.  The value I need to set it to is selectedRecord, which I have access to.

I could make changes to the app-transmission-history component to receive the parameter another way.  However, it does not seem flexible if I have to change the implementation based on how we get to it.

Answer (score 18):

Use query parameter to pass object after converting to json string.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/transmissionHistory']"
   [queryParams]="{record:selectedRecord | json }">
    {{selectedRecord.Name}}
</a>
```

In your component you can do something like this to read params:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-transmission-history'
})
export class TransmissionHistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  theRecord: Record = null;

  constructor(
      private _transmissionHistoryService: TransmissionHistoryService,
      private _route: ActivatedRoute

   ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.theRecord = JSON.parse(params.record) as Record;
      });
   }
}
```

And router config will look like as:

```
{ path: 'transmissionHistory', component: TransmissionHistoryComponent }
```

Comment: In Angular 8 I had to use queryParamMap to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look at [router parameters](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html). You can pass you param like this:

`<a [routerLink]="['/transmissionHistory', selectedRecord]">{{selectedRecord.Name}}</a>`

Than in you component you can retrive it like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-transmission-history'
})
export class TransmissionHistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  theRecord: Record = null;

  constructor(
      private _transmissionHistoryService: TransmissionHistoryService,
      private _route: ActivatedRoute

   ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.theRecord = params['record'];
      });
   }
}
```

Remember to setup this parameter in your router config:

```js
{ path: 'transmissionHistory/:record', component: TransmissionHistoryComponent }
```

Comment: This changes my implementation.  The component is used elsewhere using the @Input parameter.  Do I have to support both based on how they get here?

Comment: I guess you can but I never tried that myself. Just try!

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to pass in the `@Input` parameter as part of the routing. `@Input` is *only* for communication between a parent component and a child component. Routing to the component does not establish that parent/child relationship.

Comment: Not working for me. I don't see how this would work for objects.. can you elaborate?

Comment: this is for passing path params for passing object we need to go for query params

Answer (score 0):

**[How to pass data between routed components in Angular](https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255)**

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 8 (and above) you have to call to queryParams.

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      const userId = params['userId'];
      console.log(userId);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Angular 13, I've found there's a much easier approach.

Hope this helps everyone!
~Jedi

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'custom-component',
    templateUrl: './custom-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./custom-component.component.scss'],
})
export class YourClass {
    @Input() buttonText!: string; // * Component receives text to display as input
    @Input() routerLinkText!: string; // * component receives router link as text

...

}
```

```html
<!-- From the calling component -->
<custom-component
  [buttonText]="'Customize'"
  [routerLinkText]="['pathAsText']">
</custom-component>

<!-- Then in your custom-component -->

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="routerLinkText"> {{buttonText}} </a>
```