# In angular how to set routerLink @input parameters

Tags: angular

I want to set @input value from my routerLink  for access at my component

```js
<a href="#" routerLink="/userDetail/create" [username]="username" class="btn btn-success">create</a>
```

```js
@Input() username!: string;
```

but parameter is stillundefined , also try queryParams but is get url value not my input

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836193/angular-passing-object-to-input-parameter-with-routerlink. Can you check the top-rated answer there?

Comment: This isn't possible the way you're doing it because `<a>`n does not have an input property `username` - the component you're routing to does.

Comment: think @mike-s I didn't want to use the url parameters, but we'll do with it